# Overriding tomcat request handler to add custom behaviour

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat6, legacy-code

I have an old legacy application running on tomcat 6 on hundreds of nodes, i need to intercept all requests and introduce some minor per-processing and let the request processing continue the way it is.
I was wondering if i can override tomcat default request handling that would be only feasible way in current environment. Any information in that regard would be greatly appreciated.
Any other ideas that could be of help here are also appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you want to intercept all the requests the way to do this is with a servlet Filter https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm

Comment: That is indeed the way but considering we have this running on hundreds of notes and over two dozen applications which are in lights on mode, its not desirable to change their web.xml for them all and redeploy. It may be relatively easy to override one of tomcat class file.

Comment: I am a little confused here, it is certainly more desirable to change a web.xml file than modify Tomcat directly. The problem with modifying Tomcat is that you will suffer every time you have to upgrade Tomcat.

Comment: its less desirable in current context to edit web.xml and tomcats are not going to upgrade as such, its one of the fix we need to make to one of our very old legacy application for some reasons. Looking for a 'smart' fix/hack that can be done in one place.

Comment: Consider putting the application behind a proxy like nginx and use nginx to modify the incoming requests. Changing Tomcat is madness.